# Heroku Not Connecting to Mongo Atlas DB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

My app won't properly deploy or connect to my Mongo Atlas DB on Heroku. It keeps crashing. The heroku URL just says to do the logs, so here are the command line logs:
[image: Command line logs]

Here is what my server.js file looks like: 
[image: server.js file]

Here is what my config/keys looks like: 
[image: config/keys file]

Here is what my keys_prod.js file looks like: 
[image: keys_prod.js file]

Here is what my keys_dev.js file looks like (redacted username and password), but this is what I have for my config vars in the heroku backend as well
[image]

Also took this screenshot, not sure if it matters though:
[image]

Comment: The error is very clear, `uri parameter is undefined`. Are you sure you had set `MONGO_URI` in the Config Vars of Heroku?

Comment: This was the problem. I had set it to mongoURI like it was in the keys file, and not MONGO_URI as I declared it. Thank you for your assistance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't set the Heroku config vars correctly. I had set it to mongoURI like it was in the prod.keys JS folder instead of being MONGO_URI like I had declared it. In addition, I had to whitelist all of the ip's in Heroku's settings.

Comment: Just curious, did you have to use a Heroku provision/add on for Atlas? I'm trying to deploy a similar app and wondering if my current problem is due to no addon.

Comment: Sorry Christy, didn't see your comment ty'll just now. No I didn't have to add any additional profisions/add-ons or something else to deploy properly. Like I said I accidentally declared my database in Heroku, differently than I did in my actual app. I did mongo_URI, and when I tried to push it to Heroku it would fail cause it couldn't connect properly. When I had declared it to be MONGO_URI (all caps) in my actual prod.keys.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In deployment platforms like heroku, its hard to configure `.env` . i solved this in my project by using a npm package ***dotenv***. Whatever file need `process.env` init,use this package

common require.js way :

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

its also got some cool options to manage `env`

here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)